# HTML5 canvas select image one on top of another ignore transparent

Tags: html, canvas

How i can select image where one on top of another. 
black box is the layer size, blue circle is a first layer, red circle is a second layer.

[image]

How i can select blue circle inside a red circle

[image]

I have idea to ignore transparent, but how to make that get desired result.

Comment: What do you mean by "select"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dx=blueCenterX-mouseX;
var dy=blueCenterY-mouseY;
var isMouseInBlue=(dx*dx+dy*dy<blueRadius*blueRadius);
```